# Ruby on rails: NoMethodError in Category#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I was following the rails tutorial on creating blog. Besides Articles, I decided to create and Category. However, I'm keep getting error

```
undefined method `categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x3a26d50>:0x37f99f8>
```

and I don't get how this is a wrong variable "@category", when it is the one I was using all the time.

Rake routes:

[image]

Here is the rest of the code:

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @category = Category.all
  end 

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      redirect_to @category
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update(category_params)
      redirect_to @category
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end   

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy

    redirect_to @category
  end

  private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description, :category_primary)
  end

end
```

**new.html.rb**

```
<h1>New category</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', category_path %>
```

**_form.html.rb**

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this category from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :category_primary %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :category_primary %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Refactor your code in order to use `CategoriesController` (pluralized version of the model's name for the Controller), like you did for ArticlesController. Your routes should be like `/categories/:id/edit`, not `/category/:id/edit`

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but, here is it: How can I change the route, by changing name of the folder or cmd and what's the command ?

Comment: Please show us your routes.

Comment: 1- copy-paste your current controller in the same directory, file renamed as `categories_controller.rb` (current should be `category_controller.rb`, right?) 2- rename the class from `CategoryController` to `CategoriesController` 3- change in routes.rb `resources :category` to `resources :categories` 4- rename your folder `app/category/` to `app/categories/` go to `/categories` to test if it works 5- delete the `category_controller` and remove the line `resources :category` from your routes.rb 6- Enjoy your new routes configuration!

Comment: I put the image, check my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared routes for `Category` as a *singular* resource. They should be *plural*:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories
```

Then, in your views, change all your path names from singular to plural. For instance, the correct path is `categories_path`, not `category_path`.

Comment: I did, now im getting No route matches [GET] "/category/new", Is it because I need to change the name of the folder ?

Comment: In your views, you need to change all instances of paths for `Category` from singular to plural. For instance, use `categories_path`, instead of `category_path`.

Comment: Also rename your views folder, `app/views/category/` should be `app/views/categories/` @Xerath